# Embedded CDF Not Working

Tags: dynamic, cdf-format

I happened to be looking at an [old CDF](http://ubpdqn.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/morse-code.html) (19 months old). It previously worked and does not now. It works if downloaded (opening or at [URL](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22672121/mathematica/morse.cdf)). It requires dynamic functionality to be enabled but no longer prompts. I am uncertain how to resolve this.

I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate and await redirection.

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. Have tried in Chrome, Torch and now Firefox browsers still does not let me enter text in InputField.

Comment: @Nasser thanks for the prompt response. I had tried to simplify the scripting with no success but will try your suggestion.

Comment: Your simplified script runs the player but I still cannot type into field. Thanks for link @Nasser. I do not want to waste anybodoes time on a trivial matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF file contains `InputField[__, String, ____]` which I've seen through notepad.

Only numeric `InputField`s are going to work in FreeCDF:

[CDF, Player Pro, and Mathematica Features Comparison Chart](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html)

It works if you download it because it automatically opens in *Mathematica* if you have it.