# Upload CDF to Blogspot

Tags: cdf-format

I am trying to upload my CDF files to Blogspot. I tried the follow script:

```
<script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var cdf = new cdfplugin(); cdf.embed('https://www.dropbox.com/s/erpdi1rqwk5d3vm/Spe%20Para%20Dat.cdf', 500, 500); </script>
```

But when I try to acess it, I receive the message "File could not be loaded". I thought that maybe it was because I am using an `Import[]`, but even if I try to use a CDF Example I have the same problem. For me it seems that the problem is with the link of the file I updated.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put the CDF file in the same folder as the HTML page. And simply use embed('myCDF.cdf'). i.e use simple relative file name. It should work.

Comment: You might have to refer to the file as `https://dl.dropboxcontent.com/....` or similar - see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en)

Comment: I have CDFs on blogspot here (ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com) and my embedded CDF code is identical to yours so suggest something wrong with dropbox URL -- it doesn't look like their public linking URL.

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion of @cormullion works for me. I have another one: Can I use Import/Export with a CDF? I am trying to make an online file converter using Mathematica.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't.

Answer (score 3):

I also have uploaded CDF files to Blogspot, see e.g. [Binomial Probability](http://paul-abbott.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/binomial-probability.html), using Dropbox. However, I encountered some issues with this:

1. Is there an efficient way to link to a Dropbox folder? Instead I had to upload, share, and then modify the URLs (using the [FAQ](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en)) for both the .cdf and .png files *separately*, because Dropbox gives the files quite different URLs, even though they are in the same folder (e.g. [CDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ia50ndhlb0wkfzh/Probability1.cdf) and [PNG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nx8hzpagpng4ndy/Probability1.png)).
2. I tried viewing [Binomial Probability](http://paul-abbott.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/binomial-probability.html) on a computer without the [CDF Player](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) installed. The .png previews do not work, yet the URLs are ok, e.g. [PNG](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nx8hzpagpng4ndy/Probability1.png) **Fixed now; had wrong URL**
3. The [Binomial Probability](http://paul-abbott.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/binomial-probability.html) CDFs load and run fine under Chrome and Safari. However, when I change the controls, the page does not refresh properly.

Comment: try method here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38026/how-to-embed-a-mathematica-demonstration-in-google-sites and see if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Here are examples I made specifically for CDF on Blogspot

http://cdfexamples.blogspot.com

I recorded a walk-through talk specifically about this:

- [**Computable Document Format: Deploying Ideas to the Web - site
  1**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-cdf-virtual-workshop-2012/videos/deploying-ideas-with-cdf/)
- [**Computable Document Format: Deploying Ideas to the Web -
  site 2**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/CDF002/)

You may need to register - but it is a free video. Take a look at

11:22 minutes - micrblogging section.

Answer (score 0):

I use  Blogspot for CDF ([blog](http://ubpdqn.blogspot.com.au/)) and some [examples](http://ubpdqn.blogspot.com.au/2013_07_01_archive.html) (otherwise feel free).

I agree with TheDoctor observations.

The process changed across time.

I use DropBox (as it allows sharing file URL directly). You have to modify the code to specify the file location of the preview and the CDF.

Various browsers seem to have issues with trying to runs multiple CDF's (perhaps not surprising): hence I make one CDF per post.

Finally, there are issues related to code with user input or retrieving data using FreeCDF versus CDFPlayerPro (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29756/embedded-cdf-not-working)).