# How to embed a Mathematica demonstration in Google sites?

Tags: cdf-format, demonstrations

I want to have students submit articles that include Mathematica demonstration projects in a document that is on Google sites. I am having problems with embedding the JS code. Could you provide step-by-step instructions.

Comment: There aren't really any "steps": You're just supposed to copy the CDF Web Deployment Wizard to wherever you want the CDF to be shown. Remember to change the URL of the CDF and the image that is shown if the user does not have the CDF plugin installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to use Javascript to include CDF in a web page. (but better to use Java script, please see end of post)

Upload the CDF file (source.cdf) and the HTML page (index.htm) into a folder on the server. Keep both files in same folder for simplicity.

Edit the index.htm file using a text editor and type this line in the HTML anywhere you want the CDF to show up and play in the web page:

```
   <embed src="source.cdf" width="800" height="700">
```

Change the width and height to the correct values as needed so the the content area reserved on the web page matches well with the size of the display you want.

If this still does not work for you, please follow up with error messages. Make sure to use CDF export from Mathematica, using `Standalone` option.

[image]

From comment below, may be there is some confusion, so I thought I make the steps more clear.

Here are the steps:

**1** Student needs Mathematica to make CDF

**2** Student starts Mathematica, opens new notebook, makes HW assignment and Manipulate in the notebook.

**3** Student exports the notebook to CDF file as standalone. Now there are 2 files in student folder on their PC (university computer or student own computer). one file is called hw.nb and one called hw.cdf

**4** Student makes an index.htm file using a text editor, here is a template for one to use:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> 
> <html> 
> <head>
> <title>my HW</title> 
> </head><body>
>
>  <div> <embed src="hw.cdf" width="800" height="700"> </div>
>
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

**5** Now there are 3 files in student folder  hw.nb, hw.cdf and index.htm

**6** Student uploads the files hw.cdf and index.htm to server, on a folder there. Keeping both files in same folder on server.

**update:**

From comment below:

> It is best practice to use the JavaScript file. What it does is
>   checking if the user has the CDF player installed and if not it
>   displays an image that acts as a link to a website where it can be
>   downloaded

Comment: So I need to have Mathematica license itself and open the CDF file in it and then export it as a standalone?

Comment: @Maesumi  You need Mathematica to create CDF file from notebook file. i.e Mathematica is need for the step nb->cdf. Then CDF is used on the web page, not the .nb file. You do not need Mathematica to use CDF file. Only to create one.

Comment: It is best practice to use the JavaScript file. What it does is checking if the user has the CDF player installed and if not it displays an image that acts as a link to a website where it can be downloaded. So "no need" is a bit exaggerated, I think you should mention this downside at the top of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer, but I encountered some silly, noob issues while implementing this on Google Sites. I have referenced this answer, and posted the same as a question on Webapps Stack, at [this link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124046/can-we-use-google-drive-to-embed-mathematica-cdf-demonstrations-in-the-new-googl). If you have something to say regarding this issue (either here, or on Webapps SE), I will be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser: I have MMA 11.03 version and I cannot see the option to make a CDF standalone. How can I make a nb as a CDF standalone?